# Angular 2, textarea (append emoji with text)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I want to append emojis with the text message.

```
<textarea class="msgarea" * [(ngModel)]="msg" name="message-to-send" id="message-to-send"  placeholder="Type your message" rows="3">
</textarea>
```

to show the message with emoji

```
<div class="message-container" [innerHTML]="msg | emojis">
</div>
```

I want to show all the emoji in the text area. Please have a look at the attached image.

[image: Screenshot of application]

I am using [this](https://github.com/AhsanAyaz/ng2-emoji) reference for emojis.

Comment: How can we help?

Answer (score 0):

in html add a button and while click on button the emoji popup will come.

<button (click) ="toggleEmojiPicker()"> 
<emoji-mart class="emoji-mart" set="{{set}}" *ngIf="showEmojiPicker" (emojiSelect)="addEmoji($event)" title="Pick your emoji…">

in typescript file call this function

```
toggleEmojiPicker() {
    console.log(this.showEmojiPicker);
        this.showEmojiPicker = !this.showEmojiPicker;
  }

  addEmoji(event) {
    console.log(this.message)
    const { message } = this;
    console.log(message);
    console.log(`${event.emoji.native}`)
    const text = `${message}${event.emoji.native}`;

    this.message = text;
    // this.showEmojiPicker = false;
  }
```

[click for stackbliz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emojis) this is the stackbliz working example link.